# Conflicting static vars with non-static ones in changing values

Tags: php

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
    private $a;

    function f() {
        A::a = 0; //error
        $this->a = 0; //error
        $self::a = 0; //error
    }
}
```

How can I change `$a` in f()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Either:

```
self::$a = 0; //or
A::$a = 0;
```

If it's static, or:

```
$this->a = 0;
```

If it's not.

Comment: Wouldn't that only be the case if `$a` was declared `static`? I don't get why `$this->a = 0;` isn't working in the above code, unless he is calling `f()` statically...

Comment: @DaveRandom because in that case $a is a static and a static member doesn't belong to the object, $this returns the object reference.

Comment: Note that if you want $a as a static member, you should define it with `private static $a;`

Comment: My bad. Corrected for both static and not static.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax is:

```
self::$a
```

Answer (score 1):

obviously we all have been tricked by the title of the question, though here is how you change $a's value.

```
<?php

class A {
    private $a;

    function f() {
        //A::a = 0; //error
        $this->a = 10; //ok
        //$self::a = 0; //error
    }

    function display() {
        echo 'a : ' . $this->a . '<br>';
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->f();
$a->display();

?>
```

Output:

a : 10
if you want $a to be static use the following:

```
<?php

class A {
    private static $a;

    function f() {
        //A::$a = 0; //ok
        //$this->a = 10; //Strict Standards warning: conflicting the $a with the static $a property
        self::$a = 0; //ok
    }

    function display() {
        echo 'a : ' . self::$a . '<br>';
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->f();
$a->display();
// notice that you can't use A::$a = 10; here since $a is private

?>
```